# How to move jQuery from <head> tag to <footer> tag in Orchard 1.7.3 CMS

Tags: c#, content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have a project requirement as per which, I need to move the  tag that adds jQuery, from  tag to  tag.

I am able to find 'Documemnt.cshtml' that has the  tag. In this view file, Display(Model.Head) is used to render rest of the stuff, including jQuery.

I am having a hard time figuring out where the 'jQuery' is coming from and how to move its script tag to another location in the html document.

One of the other stuff that is rendered by 'Document.cshtml' is favicon. I tried to find that as well but to no success.

Comment: why is this even tagged jQuery...has nothing to do with it?

Comment: tagged as 'jQuery' because its 'jQuery' that needs to be looked at in Orchard CMS. So tying the relevant tags together. @charlietfl

Comment: the script being used has nothing to do with your problem which lies in your cms code . It has nothing to do with code related to jQuery

Comment: Why do you need to move jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are including jquery at the head of the document. So you need to move that to the foot. Search for `Script.Require("jQuery").AtHead()` and change it to `.AtFoot();`

Don't try to move around those shapes, it is guaranteed to end badly.